# Python, Matplotlib: Drawing a 2Dline

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a chart as follow:
[image]

I am trying to draw a line between the 2 green dots:
I have the code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
line = mpl.lines.Line2D([732009.166667,1210.0],[732009.479167, 1222.25], color="k", lw=5)
axes[i].plot(732009.166667,1210.0, 'go') 
axes[i].plot(732009.479167,1222.25, 'go')
axes[i].add_line(line)
```

But the line doesn't show up?

Is there a way to somehow inspect the content of the axes object to understand what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Line2D` creator expects the x coordinates as the first parameter and the y coordinates as the second.

It looks like you are providing x,y pairs? Your command will draw a line from (732009.166667, 732009.479167) to (1210.0, 1222.25).

Answer (score 0):

To make the line visible call `axes[i].autoscale_view()` after adding it or just use `axes[i].plot(...)` which will do it for you (why are you messing with such a low-level method like `add_line`?)

To make the line go from one point to the other use `x=[732009.166667, 732009.479167]` and `y = [1210.0, 1222.25]`.